# jQuery ajax call to MVC controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've made this work before so I'm not entirely sure what's up. It has been sometime now since I've done this. Basically taking a value from a dropdown, passing it into the ajax call then pushing it off to the Controller to render a partial view.. I am getting no errors and the partial view is simply blank. Where have I gone wrong?

Here's the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $('#selectTable').change(function () {
         var selectTables = $('#selectTable');
         var selectedOption = selectTables.find('option:selected').val();
         //pass selected table to controller
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "/Home/GetTableObject",
             data: JSON.stringify({ selectedTable: selectedOption }),
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "html",
             success: function (data) {
                 $('#ViewDetails').html(data);
             }

         });
     });

 });
```

And here's the controller:

```
public ActionResult GetTableObject(string selectedTable)
    {
        AO ao = new AO((IPrincipalBO)Session["principle"]);
        Table THETABLE = new Table();
        THETABLE = ao.GetTableObject(selectedTable);

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("_TableDetails", THETABLE);

        }
        else
        {
            //return null;
            return View(THETABLE);
        }
```

Comment: well, the partial view is blank means the model is null or empty. As you get THETABLE object from database(I suppose), what's the value of THETABLE, is there any change in db?

Comment: No changes to DB--this is all read-only.

Comment: what is happening when you are debugging your code? what are values for 'THETABLE' , 'SelectedTable', IsAjaxRequest hit?

Comment: Once the item is selected from the dropdown there seems to be a breakdown in the rest of the jQuery. Selected table is what the user has selected. Then THETABLE is an object built of that very table they selected.

Comment: @Matt Have you tried debugging using Chrome's network tab? Do you see the selectedTable in the payload? If yes then it is not getting bound by the model binder. One thing I see is that you are sending json but your datatype is html. Have you tried changing it to json?

Comment: @Matt Do you see any errors in console? Can you also post your html view code? There could be a typo somewhere.